# How can I organize a text in python with web scraping

Tags: python

I'm trying to web scrape text and organize it, the text looks something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKuXl.png
It is a mess.
How can I organize it to a json file or something?
Also I just did a basic web scrape:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
source = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar')
json_response = source.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `json` module to dump into json format:

```py
import json
import requests

source = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar').text
json_file = json.dumps(source) # Returns a str() to json_file
# alternatively:
with open("path/to/file.txt", 'w') as file:
    json.dump(source, file) # outputs json to file.txt
```